# JSP, Tomcat & MySQL replacement?

Tags: sqlite

I had little experience writing a web based inventory management system using jsp, tomcat, and db in mysql.

Ever since then, I changed my career as an embedded software engineer(so my knowledge about this topic is rather outdated), and I need to write a web format based code tracking tool with localized database and no server running like a tomcat.

So I decided to give sqllite a try since it does not require a sever running.  But I am not sure what to replace a web container with. (I might be little confused here)

basically I need something like below:
1. user accesses web based interface
2. user requests code tracking or source browsing
3. something(that does not require a server running) handles request and extracts information and displays possible matching links

db will be replaced with sqlite, and no tomcat will run. But then I am not sure how I can make "something" in 3) work :(

I'd really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by “web format”? You’re going to have a hard time doing much web programming without a web server. Unless you want to go in the direction of something like a Chrome application, you’re probably going to have to have a server of some sort.

Comment: icktoofay: what I meant by "web format", is that user will access through a web browser.  and yes I also think it will be hard or impossible to do this without server running.(But I don't know for sure)

Comment: Then unless you want to build it as a browser extension, you’re probably going to *need* a server. There’s not much to be done about that.

Comment: icktoofay: alright, then maybe I need to find a lightweight server that can be installed locally.  Thanks!

Comment: You might look into servers that are embeddable, analogously to SQLite. If you want to use Java, I believe Jetty can be embedded. There’s a number of other options out there for other languages, too.